# Store rejection because of universal link

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-universal-links

I submitted my app to Apple for review. When they try to use a universal link it opens in Safari on their iPad instead of in the app.

We tried the exact same steps they did on multiple iPhones and iPads with the same build through TestFlight and it works on all our devices and the ones our external testers use.

So I was wondering if anyone had the same issue, that universal links did not work on Apple's reviewers side, and a possible resolution.

The universal link is key to our login process. In the app you enter your email and we send you a single use link that automatically signs you into the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Services doesn't work with VPN/Proxy enabled. Which will result in failure to download the associated file for Universal Links (its getting checked/downloaded on install and app updates).

Although, I wouldn't expect Apple Reviews to not know that, so maybe its something else. Me personally, never had an issue with Universal Links during review but I'd recommend implementing a fallback scenario in your app and webpage, using Custom URL Scheme. Technically, any user might long press the URL and select "Open in Safari" instead of opening it in your app which will definitely break the flow.

Comment: Thanks, if that is the case we will provide them with an alternative method of logging in.